# Browser cache, index.php don't exists any more

Tags: php, firefox, browser-cache

The website was first developed in php and the start page was index.php

now the site is developed in python, after relauching the page many customer getting 404 error, as some how the FF had cached/mapped my `domain-name` to

`domain-name/index.php` and as now index.php no more exists the users are getting 404 error.

Is there any solution for this problem, as if the user deletes the browser cache then it works, but don't know how to convery this message to every user to delete the cache first to see this website :(

Comment: You cannot ask users to delete their cache, but you can redirect from `index.php` to your index .. use .htaccess or mime-type overwriting over index.php (to read it as a py script

Answer (score 0):

A dirty but quick solution would be to create a index.php which forwards to the new file.